# Node.Js npm PDFKit crash on calling doc.end()

Tags: node.js, module, crash, pdfkit

Helloworld!

Today, I receive a strange bug from module pdfkit:

```
TypeError: font.finalize is not a function
at PDFDocument.end (C:\Users\James\Desktop\c4t\server\node_modules\pdfkit\js\document.js:202:14)
at app.get (C:\Users\James\Desktop\c4t\server\routes\pdf.js:8:13)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\James\Desktop\c4t\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (C:\Users\James\Desktop\c4t\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\James\Desktop\c4t\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\James\Desktop\c4t\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at C:\Users\James\Desktop\c4t\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
at Function.process_params (C:\Users\James\Desktop\c4t\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
at next (C:\Users\James\Desktop\c4t\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
at module.exports (C:\Users\James\Desktop\c4t\server\tools\i18n.js:16:5)
```

I try to reinstall pdfkit and encapsulate pdfkit in a simple route:

```
var PDFDocument = require("pdfkit");
app.get("/test2", (req, res) => {
    var doc = new PDFDocument();
    doc.end();
});
```

Whenever, app crash always on calling doc.end();

Do you have suggestion why it's keep crashing?
Thanks!

James Deschênes

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found that.
I had extended object propriety like Object.prototype.foo = function(){}.
(Which was very not a good idea.)

For a reason that I don't know, pdfKit didn't like that and crash.
So I decorate the particular object that I need my foo prototype and everything was ok.